# Difference between S3+Cloudfront vs EC2 for deploying react website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While deploying my react website in AWS S3+cloudfront, I found that I can also deploy react website to EC2, Can someone explain to me when should I go for EC2 and when should I choose S3 + CloudFront?

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't developed a backend for your site then go for s3, and if you developed a custom backend (using Django, express, etc) then go for Ec2. S3 is just a storage system but you can also deploy static sites. But ec2 is a VPS. you can do whatever you want with it. And CloudFront is a CDN(Content Delivery Network) just like Cloudflare. You can use Cloudfront with both S3 and Ec2.

Comment: I think I was not able to communicate properly, I have a backend in EC2, and React app deplpyed to S3 + CloudFront. But, when should I go for EC2 for the react frontend also.

Comment: S3 is not really a web hosting service. If you have a low-traffic static website(html+css+js) then it is okay. But if your site is mid to high traffic and has dynamic web-programming language(PHP, python, ruby, etc) then you need EC2. In your case you don't need s3 to host your react frontend because you already have an Ec2 instance.